# Strange reaction for parentheses in expressions

Tags: c

I've checked this really many times....

```
int bla(int);

if (x = bla(2) < 0)  (1)
if ((x = bla(2)) < 0) (2)
```

What i want to do is to check if the return value of bla(int) is negative and then keep it to x.

However sometimes (1) works perfectly and sometimes not but i can't explain it.
Iam writing in C.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here. What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

It is because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), `<` having higher precedence than `=`:

```
if (x = bla(2) < 0)
```

results in the value of `blah(2) < 0`, which will be either `1` or `0`, being assigned to `x`.

Comment: But my question is why this is not always happening...I've finished a project without the extra parentheses and it was ok.

Comment: @user2147971, can you post a small program that reproduces it? I don't believe it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful in C#, C and C++ with =

= is an assignment operator, not a compare

It is also lower in precedence than <.

So in (1) you are assigning the result of bla(2) < 0 to x, so x will be true or false (or, more formally, a cast of true or false to the type of x). The if statement operates on the value of x; "is x true or false".

In (2) you are making x take the value of bla(2), this is an expression that has value x and you are checking whether this is less than zero. The if statement operates on the return of the question "is x less than zero".

Answer (score 2):

The reason the two statements are different is due to operator precedence...

`<` has a much higher precedence than `=`.

This means that

```
if (x = bla(2) < 0)
```

evalulates as follows: the return value of `blah(2)` is compared with zero because `<` has higher precedence than '='. If it is less than zero true results, otherwise false. This boolean value is then implicitly cast to an integer and assigned to x. Therefore, in this statement x is either true or false, and the value of x is used to evaluate the `if()` condition.

The statement

```
if ((x = bla(2)) < 0)
```

changes the order of precedence because the assignment to `x` is now surrounded by brackets, so will be done first. So x is assigned the value of `blah(2)`. The value of x is then compared and if less than zero the `if()` block runs.

What I think, from your question, you're trying to do however is...

```
int tmp = blah(2);
if(tmp < 0)
    x = tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe in the first you are making x = true or false. Because it evaluates if bla < 0 first.

In the second you are making x = bla. And THEN evaluating if x < 0.